# How to get QLineEdit text cursor position realtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

I'm trying to get the position -(x,y) coordinates- of the **text cursor** in a QLineEdit row.(not mouse position)

Considering the current position of the text cursor x = 100 and y = 100, after typing `foo` in `QLineEdit`

[image]

Assuming each letter move the position by 1, now I would like to see the position of the cursor as x = 103 and y = 100.

Is it even possible to get this text cursor position in real time? I tried `cursor method of PyQt5` but it wasn't successful.

Comment: Why do you want to calculate that position? Maybe you have a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and there is a less complicated solution

Comment: To find if the text reaches the end of QLineEdit row, so I will resize that line to make a better look(some part of text just got lost if the text goes beyond QLineEdit's width. So I will expand the line edit row in real time)

Comment: Do you want the width of the QLineEdit to match the width of the text?

Comment: If you want what you mentioned in my previous comment, your method is inappropriate, for example let's say "hello" and then move the cursor with the mouse to the middle of the two "l" and continue writing, although you calculate the mouse position that does not imply that "lo" do not hide.

Comment: Well yes, basically I just want to expand width of QLineEdit if the user input a long text which has bigger width than QLineEdit.

Comment: some feedback??